# Plotly express bar re-orders the x-axis due to missing data

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-express

I have some data which includes dates in a year-quarter format.

Sorting the dataframe works fine, however when plotting the data, `Plotly` automatically re-orders the x-axis, by placing data with missing values at the end, instead of adhering to the desired order.

```
# Example data that is not yet ordered on 'Date'
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
df = pd.DataFrame([
       ['2021-Q4', 'A', 1],
       ['2021-Q4', 'B', 5],
       ['2022-Q1', 'B', 5],
       ['2023-Q2', 'B', 3],
       ['2023-Q3', 'B', 16],
       ['2022-Q2', 'B', 4],
       ['2022-Q2', 'A', 1],
       ['2022-Q3', 'B', 5],
       ['2022-Q4', 'B', 6],
       ['2022-Q4', 'A', 4],
       ['2023-Q1', 'A', 1],
       ['2023-Q1', 'B', 9],
       ['2023-Q3', 'A', 1]
     ], columns=['Date', 'Type', 'Count'])

# we explicity order the data
# Note that now the 2022-Q1 is in between 2021-Q4 and 2022-Q2
df = df.sort_values('Date', key=lambda e: e.replace('Q',''))

# Now the x-axis and the broken chronology, i.e., 2022-Q1 at the end
fg = px.bar(df, x="Date", y="Count", color="Type", barmode="group")
fg.show()
```

[image]

My desired behavior is that the x-axis remains in the same order as the `df` is after applying `sort_values`. Instead, rows with empty data are places in the end, no longer on the chronological order. How can I override this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout can be updated to specify the category order:

```
fg.update_layout(xaxis={'categoryorder':'category ascending'})
```

This outputs:

[image]

Please refer to [this page](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/) for more information on how to deal with sorted or ordered categories.

Comment: Thank you, that does it. However the link appears to be broken!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just updated the link.